# C# Error Parsing the Query Token Line number 1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

C# Error Parsing the Query Token Line number 1

```
     cmmd.CommandText = "Select total from Dept_Sales where department ='" + department + "'";
     var dtotal = cmmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     var nntotal = dtotal + price;

     SqlCeCommand cmmmmd = new SqlCeCommand("update [Dept_Sales] SET [total]=@val1) where [department]=@val2", conn);
     {
     cmmmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", nntotal);
     cmmmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", department);
     cmmmmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
     cmmmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()           }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     also dtotal =3.51
     and price = 3.51
     nntotal = 7.02
```

i think there may be a promblem in my query i have changed it 15 times same error can anyone give me any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmatched closing parenthesis:

```
[total]=@val1)
            ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extera `)` from line #4 may helps. So it should be this way:

```
SqlCeCommand cmmmmd = 
    new SqlCeCommand("update [Dept_Sales] SET [total]=@val1 
                      where [department]=@val2", conn);
```